# What are some good resources to study probabilistic coupling?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, coupling

I was reading a research paper where the author uses probabilistic coupling. The paper is very badly written, and a lot of details are just directly written without any justification. So, they define a probabilistic coupling over two random experiments. I wanted to know a source where probabilistic coupling is written/explained in a reasonable detail. It would be good if the resource has some problems that I can practice.

Comment: Maybe chapter 5 in https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf

Comment: I haven't read it, but the book [Lectures on the Coupling Method](https://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Coupling-Method-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486421457) by T. Lindvall sounds like it could be useful. No exercises, however.